# What is the easiest and/or safest law enforcement job?

Tags: job-search

I applied to become a police officer just because it seemed like it might be an interesting job that I might be good at. My application got accepted and I am currently in the process of taking all the tests. However, now I'm not so sure that it's really something I want to do. Aside from not having a set schedule and working long hours, I really don't enjoy interacting with people, especially hostile people, and would really rather not get shot or stabbed. So while I'm thinking on whether to bail on this endeavor or not, I was wondering what the safest police officer job might be. I was thinking that crime scene investigation might be something up my ally since you get there after all the shooting and stabbing and you really get to use yer brain to figure things out rather than trying to defuse a dangerous situation (i'm 5'2", 96 lb), but I don't know if I'd have to do patrolling for many years before I get there first. 
I guess if nothing else I could go through training just to have some kind of pay in the meantime and decide afterwards.
Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, I got out after my second year because it wasn't really working out for me, so now I'm looking for something else to do. Guess I still haven't quite figure out what I want to do with my life, so just trying different things. How will I know if I really want till I try it? And there are plenty of law enforcement jobs where one doesn't have to be directly in the line of fire, so I'm not sure why you downvoted my question.

Comment: "What job should I take" is off topic here, I'm afraid.

Comment: @keshlam, errrr ... ok, my bad ... i figured since it's about work, workplace is the place to ask ...  which stack exchange would be more appropriate?

Comment: I don't think this question would be on-topic at any Stack Exchange site - it's far too personal to your own circumstances to be a useful question for others.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, would it be less personal to just ask "What is the safest law enforcement job"? That seems like a pretty legitimate question.

Comment: @Solarmew This type of question doesn't belong on any stack. Even if you apparently dislike interacting with people, that's the best and arguably only way to get decent advice for your situation. There are typically counsellors available at university and you can ask friends and family for advice. It's good that you're thinking of the direction you want to go before you complete your studies but you shouldn't rely on the internet to tell you how to plan your life.

Comment: they're all potentially dangerous, you sign up to if need be put your life on the line. Surprised you got in at 5 foot 2.

Answer (score 4):

Certain jobs -- soldier, cop, fireman, EMT -- assume the privilege of guarding other people. Such jobs require focus and dedication beyond that needed to just get up in the morning and go to work.

"it might be an interesting job" "not so sure that it's really something I want to do" "really don't enjoy interacting with people, especially hostile people" "would really rather not get shot or stabbed" "go through training just to have some kind of pay in the meantime" "I'm looking for something else to do" "still haven't quite figure out what I want to do with my life" "plenty of law enforcement jobs where one doesn't have to be directly in the line of fire" -- I have never seen so many weasel phrases from one potential applicant. Jobs where your comrades' mortal safety depends on your focus and dedication are not for those who are conflicted about their own focus and dedication.

There are jobs in the public sector that serve the guard-type departments, such as personnel administrator, department accountant, purchasing, etc. but these jobs could be in any department and in fact workers with these skills often transfer in and out of police departments etc. without additional training or certification. One of these might be more suitable for you. These are not jobs that you would get by "[applying] to become a police officer", or fireman etc.

There's nothing wrong with not knowing what you want to do with your life, and wanting to try out various jobs to see what you like. But please, just don't get yourself, or anyone else, killed while you're experimenting.

Comment: No need to get rude. Just because someone might not be sure about a job at first, doesn't mean they won't be good at it. Besides, it's better to be aware of your own conflicts with focus and dedication in the beginning than when you're knee-deep in some assignment and suddenly realize that's not what you signed up for, don't you think?.. I served three years in the air force and did a tour in iraq and did my job just fine, thank you.